# how to save belongsToMany for edit action in CakePHP 3.x?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

`Products` belongsToMany `ProductCircles` through `ProductsInCircles`.

`ProductsInCirclesTable.php`

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    $this->table('products_in_circles');
    $this->displayField('id');
    $this->primaryKey('id');
    $this->belongsTo('Products', [
        'foreignKey' => 'product_id'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('ProductCircles', [
        'foreignKey' => 'product_circle_id'
    ]);
}
```

`ProductsTable.php`

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    $this->table('products');
    $this->displayField('name');
    $this->primaryKey('id');
    $this->belongsToMany('ProductCircles', [
        'through' => 'ProductsInCircles',
    ]);
}
```

When I edit a `Product` via `products/edit/{id}`, I will provide the following data from `$this->request->data`

```
Array
(
    [name] => Piuma
    [attributes_in_json] => {"size":"large"}
    [rooms] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
        )

    [styles] => Array
        (
            [0] => 15
            [1] => 16
        )

    [materials] => Array
        (
            [0] => 27
        )

    [product_circles] => Array
        (
            [_ids] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                    [1] => 15
                    [2] => 16
                    [3] => 27
                )

        )

    [associated] => Array
        (
            [0] => ProductCircles
        )

)
```

The following code did not save the associated data into `products_in_circles` table

```
$product = $this->Products->patchEntity($product, $this->request->data);
$product->dirty('product_circles', true);
if ($this->Products->save($product)) {
```

I have also tried

```
$product = $this->Products->patchEntity($product, $this->request->data, ['associated' => ['ProductCircles']]);
if ($this->Products->save($product)) {
```

AND

```
$product = $this->Products->patchEntity($product, $this->request->data);
if ($this->Products->save($product, ['associated' => ['ProductCircles']])) {
```

AND

```
$product = $this->Products->patchEntity($product, $this->request->data, ['ProductCircles']);
if ($this->Products->save($product)) {
```

How do I save and persist these into the `products_in_circles` table properly?

I definitely want to use the `append` option as well instead of `replace`.

I have looked at the docs and the example is clearer for creating new entity. Mine is for editing an existing entity.

Also, I cannot find out where I turn on the `append` option. See http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-belongstomany-associations

I suspect I made a mistake in the way the data is structured.

Please advise.

**EDIT**

Product Entity

```
class Product extends Entity
{

    /**
     * Fields that can be mass assigned using newEntity() or patchEntity().
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_accessible = [
        'name' => true,
        'attributes_in_json' => true,
        'created_by' => true,
        'modified_by' => true,
        'prices' => true,
    ];
}
```

Comment: is the `product_circles` property accessible in your Product entity class?

Comment: added Product Entity code. Nope, I do not have product_circles as accessible property. Is that crucial?

Comment: Okay, looks like that was necessary. Thank you Lorenzo

Comment: did you figure out where to use the "append" option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to add product_circles as the accessible property in the `Product` entity class.

```
class Product extends Entity
{

    /**
     * Fields that can be mass assigned using newEntity() or patchEntity().
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_accessible = [
        'name' => true,
        'attributes_in_json' => true,
        'created_by' => true,
        'modified_by' => true,
        'prices' => true,
        'product_circles' => true,
    ];
}
```

Credit goes to Jose Lorenzo in the comments section.